# React function component not rendering an app component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I'm a newbie to React. My array of messages is not rendering. I've verified that my array, which is part of the Messages state, is getting made properly, so I'm really confused as to why this is happening. Do I need to make all the components functional components?

ChatApp.js uses Messages.js which is a list that is generated from Message.js

**ChatApp.js**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import config from '../config';
import Messages from './Messages';
import ChatInput from './ChatInput';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Image from 'react-bootstrap/Image';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Media from 'react-bootstrap/Media';
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

require('../styles/ChatApp.css');


const ChatApp = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = React.useState([]);
  const userId = useSelector(state => state.profile.profile._id);
  const role = useSelector(state => state.profile.profile.role);

  const addMessage = (message) => {
   const messagess = [...messages];
   messagess.push(message); 
   setMessages(messagess);
   console.log(messagess);   
   }

   const sendHandler = (message) => {

    const messageObject = {
      username: userId,
      message
    };
    addMessage(messageObject);
   }
   

     return (

<div className="landing">
<Container>
 <Row className="mt-5">
   <Col md={{ span: 8, offset: 2 }}>

     <Card style={{ height: "36rem" }} border="dark">  
       <Messages msgs={messages} />
       <Card.Footer>
       <ChatInput onSend={sendHandler}>
         </ChatInput>
       </Card.Footer>
     </Card>
   </Col>
 </Row>
</Container>
</div>
   )
 };


ChatApp.defaultProps = {
 username: 'anonymous'
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
 return {
   authUser: state.auth.user,
   profile: state.profile.profile
 };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(ChatApp);
```

**Messages.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import Message from './Message';

class Messages extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate() {
    // There is a new message in the state, scroll to bottom of list
    const objDiv = document.getElementById('messageList');
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
  }

  render() {
    // Loop through all the messages in the state and create a Message component
    const messages = this.props.messages.map((message, i) => {
        return (
          <Message
            key={i}
            username={message.username}
            message={message.message}
            fromMe={message.fromMe} />
        );
      });

    return (
      <div className='messages' id='messageList'>
        { messages }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Messages.defaultProps = {
  messages: []
};

export default Messages;
```

**Message.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Image from 'react-bootstrap/Image'
import Media from 'react-bootstrap/Media';

class Message extends React.Component {
  render() {
   

    return (
    

      <ul className="list-unstyled">
        <Media as="li"> 
              <Media.Body>
                <h6 className="font-weight-bold">{ this.props.username }</h6>
                <p>
                { this.props.message }
              </p>
                <p className="small text-muted">
                  3 hrs ago
              </p>
              </Media.Body>
            </Media>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

Message.defaultProps = {
  message: '',
  username: '',
  to: '',
  fromMe: false
};

export default Message;
```

Comment: you can t redeclare messages.   
const addMessage = (message) => {
   setMessages(prevMessages=>[...prevMessages, message]);
   console.log(messagess);   
   }

Comment: @tachko even when I use the const "addMessage = (message) => { setMessages(prevMessages=>[...prevMessages, message]);" method, my messages still do not render.

Comment: You're passing `Messages` a prop called `msgs` but then attempting to access it as `this.props.messages`. It's basically a typo. Your default props is the only thing stopping it from breaking.

Comment: @BrianThompson thank you, that fixed it :)